# Eclipse Can't Find Latest Java 1.6 Methods for XMLOutputFactory

Tags: java, stax

I'm trying to use the `newFactory()` method for `XMLOutputFactory`, which was added in Java 6. But Eclipse keeps flagging `newFactory()` as *undefined* for the type `XMLOutputFactory`. JRE7 is the only runtime installed and in the build path of new Java projects. The project itself only has JRE7 (JRE System Library) and Ivy set up. The error I keep getting is

```
The method newFactory() is undefined for the type XMLOutputFactory
```

Any ideas how to get Eclipse to accept `newFactory`? Pretty much just using `return XMLOutputFactory.newFactory()` as the only place where the function is called.

Comment: Have you set the compiler compliance level to 1.6 ?

Comment: Yep. The default compliance level is set to 1.6 for new Java projects using Window->Preferences.

For this project where the problem occurs specifically, compliance is set to 1.7 (otherwise get a bunch of other errors).

Comment: So you can check in your import, that you really import the proper class.

Comment: You mean the import statement? It's "import javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory;" which seems right...

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild. Sometimes this helps.

Comment: Did that too. Also refreshed the project, all other projects, and resolved Ivy several times as well. Technically, I could just change newFactory() to newInstance() (old Java 5 equivalent which is still not deprecated) but I want to figure out why I can't use newFactory() as of now still.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and it is resolved by using:
`XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();`
you can visit:

[click here for full description](http://edelstein.pebbles.cs.cmu.edu/jadeite/main.php?api=java6&state=class&package=javax.xml.stream&class=XMLInputFactory)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I fixed it by removing StAX from my classpath, because the version of XMLOutputFactory that comes with Java 7 provides the newFactory method, but the version of XMLOutputFactory that comes with StAX doesn't have it.

Comment: It worked. I excluded it from my gradle build using the dependenceis task to find the path and adding the exclude section to the parent dependency

Answer (score 2):

I build and imported Apache Phoenix project. class XMLResultHandler was giving the same error "The method newFactory() is undefined for the type XMLOutputFactory". 
I solved the problem by changing the order of Java System Library and stax-api-1.0-2.jar.

[After correction eclipse project Library order snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBcUm.png)